# using an boost::iostreams::array_sink with a boost::array<char, n>

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, boost, boost-iostreams

The example (reproduced below [from here](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.iostreams-devices)) shows that, using a stream of array_sink, I can get output stream functionality on a char array.

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::iostreams;

int main()
{
    char buffer[16];
    array_sink sink{buffer};
    stream<array_sink> os{sink};
    os << "Boost" << std::flush;
    std::cout.write(buffer, 5);
}
```

What I need though is to get a stream of array_sink from a boost::array.
e.g.

```
...
using namespace boost::iostreams;

boost::array<char, 16384> headerBuf;

array_sink          sink    {headerBuf};
stream<array_sink>  os      {sink};

os << "somedata";
```

when compiling this under gcc 4.4.7, I get the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::iostreams::basic_array_sink<char>::basic_array_sink(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
```

I'm guessing the initializer list may not be supported by gcc 4.4.7, although in general, is there an alternative method of initializing an array_sink with a boost::array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/array.html#array_sink

Use the begin/end or begin/length ctors.

```
array_sink          sink    {headerBuf.begin(), headerBuf.size()};
```